# Functions in C Headers?

Tags: c, function, header

I've heard that you put function prototypes in header files and then put the function definitions in a .c file. However, what is this .c file. For example, if you were to include a file "foo.h", would you call the aforementioned .c file "foo.c", put the function definition in it, put it in the same place as the foo.h, and when you try to include foo.h, will the function carry over from the c file and will the function be ready to use?

Comment: The reason not to put functions in header files is that if you include it in two .c files, you will get two definitions of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, just putting the `.c` with the `.h` and including it in your code doesn't magically carry over the definition of the functions too.

You need to compile the `foo.c` separately into an object file (in case of Linux, it is a `.o` file). For example using the command -

```
gcc -c foo.c -o foo.o
```

Now this `foo.o` needs to be *linked* to your actual program. This can be done by simply passing the object file while compiling as

```
gcc test.c foo.o -o test.out
```

If you do not link the `foo.o` with your program, your linker won't be able to find the implementations for the functions defined in it and will throw a linker error as -

> Undefined reference to function `foo_function`.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer! Just one more question: in the foo.c, do you have to include the foo.h, or do you just define the function with no mention of the header?

Comment: @J.S. It is usually a good idea to include the headers in the corresponding `.c` too so that the types in the headers match the types in the definition. If they are different by mistake, the compiler will report an error.

Comment: OK, thanks for all your help, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @J.S. I would go a little farther than "usually a good idea" and say, "Yes, you have to".  It will work without it, it's true, but it opens up a huge hole in the type-checking system.  (Me, I wish compilers would complain about functions being defined without a prototype in scope, just as they complain about functions being called without a prototype in scope.)

Comment: Modern GCC does complain a lot more about functions called without a declaration in scope — GCC compilers version 5.0 and later use C11 mode by default.  They still don't automatically complain about no prototype; you can enable that with `-Wstrict-prototypes` (which is not a part of `-Wall` or `-Wextra`, to my considerable surprise).  There's also `-Wold-style-definition` and `-Wold-style-declaration` and `-Wmissing-prototypes`.

Comment: I recommend passing at least `-Wall -Wextra -g` to `gcc` and probably `-Wstrict-prototype` also

Comment: @For those interested in this subtopic, see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401100/compiler-warning-for-function-defined-without-prototype).

Comment: @J.S. As others have clarified it, including the header is essential. Infact on many systems, the linker does not (and cannot) check for type mismatch because of lack of a proper name mangling scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Header files are just conventional. The [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) is handling [`#include` directive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive)s and the compiler sees the preprocessed input (but you might copy and paste huge amount of C code to get the equivalent of `#include`). Actually, the preprocessor don't care if you `#include "foo.h"` or `#include "foo.c"`, but the later is often poor taste. Naming header files with a `.h` suffix is just a (very common) *convention*.

So, if you have a function definition in a header included in several source files (technically [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))s), that function definition is in every such translation unit.

What happen then depends on that function definition (it should be `static` or even better `static inline`).

In practice, you should restrict function definitions in header to be `static`  or `static inline`. If you don't declare `static`  a function definition `void foo(int x) { /* something */ }` in a header which is included in several `*.c`  files you'll have multiple-definitions of `foo` errors at [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) time. And the main interest of putting a function definition in a header is to enable inlining (hence the `inline` hint); otherwise (the usual case), you don't need that and you just put the function prototype in the header file and the function definition in *one* of your `*.c` files.

If you have short and quick running functions, it could be wise to *define* them as `static inline` (so give their bodies) in your header files (but of course, that increases the compilation time). Otherwise, it is not worth the burden.

Some header files might have long macros (of dozens of physical lines, all of them except the last ended with a backslash) expanded to function definitions. Look into [sglib](http://sglib.sourceforge.net/) for an example.

Notice that `inline` is today (like `register` was in the previous decade) just a *hint* to the compiler (for [inline expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) optimization), which is allowed to ignore it (also, many [optimizing compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) are able to inline functions without any annotation, provided they know the body of the called function).

Don't forget to enable all warnings and debug info. [With](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) GCC, use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`, perhaps with `-Wstrict-prototypes`. You could get the included files with `-H` (and the preprocessed form with `-C -E`).

Refer to some C [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) site and to the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) for more details. Read the [GNU `cpp` reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) manual about preprocessing.