# Is including header file necessary?

Tags: c++

add.h:

```
int add(int x, int y); // function prototype for add.h -- don't forget the semicolon!
```

In order to use this header file in main.cpp, we have to #include it (using quotes, not angle brackets).

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "add.h" // Insert contents of add.h at this point.  Note use of double quotes here.

int main()
{
    std::cout << "The sum of 3 and 4 is " << add(3, 4) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

add.cpp:

```
#include "add.h"

int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

Hi, I was wondering, why do we have #include "add.h" in file add.cpp? I do not think it is necessary.

Comment: _why do we have #include "add.h" in file add.cpp? I do not think it is necessary._ Not in your specific case but in most others. Your `add.h` declares a function only. The definition of this function in `add.cpp` would work without the declaration as well. You're correct. But what if you have multiple functions which call each other? What if you have a class in `.h` which shall be defined in `.cpp`? A module (`.cpp`) with an interface (aka header, `.h`), that's the usual convention. (And, usually both with the same name - for convenience and readability.) ;-)

Comment: Most compiler will complain that `add` was defined, but not declared (at least clang) when compiling `add.cpp`.

Comment: @MarekR Really? That wonders me. (I couldn't reproduce: [**Test on Compiler Explorer**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qRnB8E).)

Comment: `was defined, but not declared` - how is that possible? Function definition is also a function declaration, from what I remember.

Comment: It's needed to link the definition in your cpp. Without it when you call add via the header from main, you'd be trying to call a declaration with no definition and get a link error.

Comment: @GeorgesupportsGoFundMonica I doubt. A non-static function definition is `extern`. The linker will find it with or without prior declaration.

Comment: In a way you don't. You could just type "extern int add(int, int)" in main.cpp to tell the compiler it exists and the linker should then find it. But then you have to do this for all externs you use. Easier just to include the header file although in this particular instance ir is as easy to type "extern..." as to type  "#include..." so whichever floats your boat

Comment: Always `#include`ing the corresponding header in the source file can catch errors where you change the signature in one but not the other, earlier than these might otherwise be caught. And it just makes sense. Think interface and implementation.

Comment: @Scheff yes really https://stackoverflow.com/q/50401100/1387438

Comment: @MarekR The linked answer is about C. (I'm not that up-to-date in C anymore.) Are you _really_ sure that it's true for C++ as well?

Comment: I've seen this on some C++ project where global functions where used. Note that many `C` specific features compilers by default make available in C++ code even when this is against C++ standard (for example VLA).

Comment: @MarekR I clicked a bit further and found (about `-Wmissing-prototypes`): [-Wmissing-prototypes (C and Objective-C only)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wmissing-prototypes). ;-)

Comment: ok. Had some project which mixed both :| sorry.

Answer (score 5):

In C++ each file is compiled separately in what is called a "[translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))". Basically in most of the setups, a translation unit is compilation of a single .cpp file.

When the compiler compiles one .cpp file he doesn't see the information stored in other .cpp files. It only sees this single .cpp file.

The [`#include`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include) is a simple text replacement instruction. `#include "add.h"` tells the compiler to insert the content of the file `add.h` (found in compiler specific include search paths) just as-is into the file `main.cpp`.

When you write `add(3, 4)` the compiler needs to know about `add`. What does it return? Does it take `unsigned long long` arguments or `unsigned char` arguments? To tell compiler about a function return type and arguments type we use a [function declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_declaration), for example `int add(int, int);`. Or `int add(int something, int anything);`. The argument names in function declaration serve here as the documentation for the programmer - the important part for the compiler are types.

The compiler doesn't see the information stored in `add.cpp`. It is (typically) compiled as a separate translation unit. So we need to tell the compiler about the types around `add()` function. That information typically is stored in a header that is included in both translation units - in the "consumer" `main.cpp` that uses the function and in the "implementation" `add.cpp` that implements the function and what does it do. Typically the header is named the same as the file that implements the function(s) with a different extension.

> why do we have #include "add.h" in file add.cpp?

Mostly as a defense for the programmer against errors and changes. Because two translation units are compiled separately, it's the programmer job to properly synchronize information between them.

If you would change in `#include "add.h"` ex. the return type of the function `add`, but forgot to change it in the implementation, the compiler would complain. Usage of the headers becomes more and more important when using `class`es, which define all the class members, inheritances etc. in one place in a header.

To "synchronize" the interface and the implementation for less errors, we include the header with the declaration in both the consumer and in the implementation. That way if you happen to change ex. the return type of the function, but forgot to change the `add.cpp` file, the compiler will complain.

> I do not think it is necessary.

For such a simple project, it is not necessary, but I would consider it to be "bad style" or "spaghetti code" if you wouldn't do it. The `add.h` file tells me about what is in `add.cpp` file - what functions are defined them.

Comment: IMHO, the question of OP wasn't Why the `#include "add.h"` in `main.cpp` but Why the `#include "add.h"` in `add.cpp`. You yourself pointed out that it's not necessary in this specific case. IMHO, the OP wonders why it's done for all that (probably having seen similar examples everywhere). However, I spent my upvote - nice answer. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> why do we have `#include "add.h"` in file `add.cpp`? I do not think it is necessary.

In *this* case, no, it is not necessary, but nor is it harmful.

Blanket style rules like this help avoid problems that can occur when code changes, especially in large projects with multiple authors.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, It is not necessary. But, in a real project, with more functions, or class declarations. It will become mandatory.

So, it's a good practice, and Compiler takes a little time to parse it.