# How can I find free functions that should have been declared as static?

Tags: c++, c

In our codebase, I often come across functions defined in the .cpp as

```
void foo() { ... }
```

by they do not appear in the corresponding header.
These are implicitly `extern`.

For most of these cases, it is a smell that the function should have been defined as `static`.
I would like to collect these cases and review them.
The intention is to clear all accidental external linkages.

**Q:** Is there a practical way to identify such definitions? or is there some tool?

I was thinking of using `nm` to find external symbols, and then search for them in the corresponding headers.
If they are not found, then they should have internal linkage.
But I don't know how to tell if a symbol is a free function or not.

Comment: C or C++ ? Please pick one language

Comment: Maybe this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401100/compiler-warning-for-function-defined-without-prototype-in-scope At least gcc has -Wmissing-declarations

Comment: For small projects, just use `grep` (or similar command) to find all uses of non-member functions in other files (both source and header). For larger projects where it becomes too much use a static analysis tool to help you. Your IDE might also have functionality to find uses of a function, which makes it easy to see if it's used in other source or header files.

Comment: Move a bunch of them (not one at a time) into an anonymous namespace and rebuild, the linker will tell you the ones you need to move back to the global scope. Repeat.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I am interested in both, actually.

Comment: @SupportUkraine, if I use `-Wmissing-declarations` then a will valid definition like `static void foo() {..}` be invalid because provide a matching declaration isn't provided?

Comment: @GrimFandango I don't think so... The `static` means (AFAIK) that you will not get a warning. But I'm not an expert here so... try it out.

Answer (score 2):

MISRA C and MISRA C++ have rules stating that functions/variables declared at file scope and only used in one translation unit should be declared as `static` to ensure internal linkage. Or in case of file scope variables only used by one function, declare them at local scope instead. See for example MISRA C:2012 rules 8.7, 8.8 and 8.9. These are very sound rules that apply to *all* C and C++ programs, not just those written for critical systems.

So you could run a MISRA checking static analyser and it will point out which functions and variables that need changing. Any half-decent static analyser will have MISRA support.

Though please note that tool recommendation questions are explicitly off-topic here, so kindly don't ask which tool to pick. Such questions may be on-topic at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com