# Regarding mainstream compilers and int main(){} in C23

Tags: c, gcc, clang, function-prototypes, c23

My program:

```
int main(){}
```

In upcoming C23, non-prototype and "K&R style" functions are removed. I realize that C23 is not yet formally released, but the current behavior of gcc and clang is confusing me.

- Compiling the above with gcc (trunk) `-std=c2x -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra`:
  no diagnostics.
- Compiling the above with clang 16.0.0 `-std=c2x -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra`:
  no diagnostics.
- Compiling the above with clang 16.0.0 `-pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra`:

  > error: a function declaration without a prototype is deprecated in all versions of C [-Werror,-Wstrict-prototypes]

How am I to make any sense of this? I can understand if gcc has not yet implemented this, since C23 is after all not yet released, but why is clang giving the warning when I *don't* specify `-std=c2x`?

Comment: Why are you asking this question here and not on the GCC and Clang user support mailing lists? It is unlikely that anyone here can give a definitive answer.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @zwol Because I try to ask here first before spamming down those lists with things that are already well-known bugs or no bugs at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use clang 16.0.0 and don't use `-std=c2x` it defaults to some version that is not c2x (probably c11, maybe c17).

In that version, your program has a `function declaration without a prototype`, which is `deprecated in all versions of C` (including that one).

In C2X, they removed the possibility of declaring functions without prototypes. Every function declaration has a prototype. So this same code is a function declaration *with* a prototype with no parameters.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that I have missed this part in C23 (draft N3096) 6.7.6.3/13:

> For a function declarator without a parameter type list: the effect is as if it were declared with a parameter type list consisting of the keyword `void`. A function declarator provides a prototype for the function.

That is, C23 will behave as C++ already does.