# Android Studio/ Flutter/ Firebase Problem

Tags: xcode, firebase, cocoapods, flutter-dependencies

I am very new to coding and do not really have a clue TBH. I have Android Studio and I am using Flutter in this.
I am using a Macbook and trying to build a multi platform mobile app App. I have the homescreen, Login page and sign up page set up. As soon as I tried to add Firebase to the code I started getting issues. Th latest error message I am getting is

```
simonweaver@Simons-MacBook-Air ios % flutter run
Changing current working directory to: /Users/simonweaver/StudioProjects/untitled3
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro in debug mode...
Updating minimum iOS deployment target to 11.0.
Upgrading Podfile
Updating project for Xcode compatibility.
Upgrading project.pbxproj
Upgrading Runner.xcscheme
Running pod install...                                             928ms
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                            4.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Semantic Issue (Xcode): A function declaration without a prototype is deprecated in all versions of C
/Users/simonweaver/StudioProjects/untitled3/ios/Pods/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport/GDTCORLibrary/GDTCORPlatform.m:86:42


Semantic Issue (Xcode): A function declaration without a prototype is deprecated in all versions of C
/Users/simonweaver/StudioProjects/untitled3/ios/Pods/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport/GDTCORLibrary/GDTCORPlatform.m:101:60


Semantic Issue (Xcode): A function declaration without a prototype is deprecated in all versions of C
/Users/simonweaver/StudioProjects/untitled3/ios/Pods/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport/GDTCORLibrary/GDTCORPlatform.m:156:36


Error (Xcode): File not found: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a


Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro.
simonweaver@Simons-MacBook-Air ios % flutter run
Changing current working directory to: /Users/simonweaver/StudioProjects/untitled3
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                             818ms
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                         4.3s
Xcode build done.                                           24.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'firebase_auth' not found
/Users/simonweaver/StudioProjects/untitled3/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:11:8


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro.
```

Pulling my hair out (what little I have left) any assistance would be gratefully received.

I don't really know what I am doing. I have even tried Chatgpt and even it is struggling.

Comment: The error message you posted literally tells you what the issue is. `Failed to build iOS app Semantic Issue (Xcode): A function declaration without a prototype is deprecated in all versions of C`. A lot of [results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75943541/a-function-declaration-without-a-prototype-is-deprecated-in-all-versions-of-c) show up when you google this issue... Have you tried looking up solutions for that issue specifically rather than pasting a massive error message? If so, could you please narrow down your question (include a sentence with a question mark) :)