# Why do we need return type and parameter type in funtion declarations?

Tags: c, forward-declaration

I've been told we somehow need them so the compiler can continue onwards without having read the definition yet.

Somehow we need them in order for the program to work properly, to avoid conflicts between functions.

Please explain.

Comment: Actually you may omit the parameter list in a function declaration. Pay attention to that there is a typo in the function definition.  Instead of int square(num){ you have to write int square(int num){

Comment: In the dark ages you could actually get away with calling functions without any declarations at all. They'd then get the parameter signature of the first call (if I remember correctly) and they were assumed to return `int`. Totally dangerous

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes, that too... Until C23! Hooray! :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Could you provide a link to the last C 23 draft as a pdf file?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Sure: [C23 draft pdf](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n3088.pdf)

Comment: @TedLyngmo The problem is where to find time to read C++20 Standard, C++23 Standard, and now C23 Standard!:)

Comment: @JohnBollinger _"all the arguments to each call are subject to the default argument promotions"_ - yes, that. Thanks! ... and that the return type was `int` too, right?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Under C23, will it be possible to define a function which takes a pointer to its own type as an argument?  Before C23, one could do that by having a function accept a pointer to a function with unspecified arguments.  Does C23 provide a replacement, or does ti simply break programs that require that ability?

Comment: Sorry, @TedLyngmo, I pulled my previous comment out from under you.  But yes, default argument promotions (just like still apply to variadic arguments), and defaulting to returning `int`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger No worries. :-) Ok, yes, that was risky business.

Comment: @supercat: I have no idea yet. I heard about the above change the other day and haven't really thought much about it other than that sounds like a good idea.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Specifying that function calls must be made to functions with prototypes *in the absence of a documented extension* allowing otherwise (as might be needed when calling code written in other languages) is probably reasonable.  Requiring that all function types specify arguments, however, would make some constructs that had been supportable in somewhat typesafe fashion unsupportable except by replacing double-indirect function pointers with completely-untyped `void*`.

Comment: @supercat Yes, in that regard, it does seem like a breaking change. I tried it out just now to see if it was possible to "trick" it with something like `void foo(typeof(foo) fp) {}` - but, nope. :)

Comment: @supercat, the original proposal [n2432](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2432.pdf) that removed support for function definitions without prototypes retained the ability to declare functions without prototyping them, but a subsequent proposal, [n2841](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2841.htm), took that out, too.  In C23, every function declaration provides a prototype, whether it is part of a function definition or not.  If the parameter list is empty then that means the function accepts no parameters.

Comment: I think that means that C23 has nothing like an incomplete function type, which is what you need to declare a function that accepts a pointer to its own type as an argument.  However, I guess you can play games with pointer conversions to adapt code that wants such a feature to C23.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: That would be fine if compilers could reasonably be trusted not to interpret the clause "The standard imposes no requirements" as meaning "An implementation that processes the construct nonsensically would in no way be inferior to one that process it meaningfully".

Comment: @supercat, I guess you could also rely on the fact that you can forward declare a structure or union type.  That allows for defining a structure or union that contains a pointer to a function that has a parameter of the structure or union type.  This is not quite as easy to use as a function that accepts the wanted function pointer directly, but it does allow the function pointer involved to be declared with a prototype, which carries some advantage even in C17 and earlier.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: That would be a substitute if redundant identical struct definitions would be ignored, but there's no nice pattern for ensuring that every such structure will be defined exactly once.

Comment: @supercat I suppose I'm going to have to update [Question 1.22](https://c-faq.com/decl/recurfuncp.html).

Comment: @SteveSummit: Having a state machine function return a pointer to the next function that should be invoked was always awkward, but that problem had previously not existed when passing arguments of function type.  If C had includes a "pointer to any function" type analogous to `void*` which, like `void*` would need to be cast to an actual function type prior to use, that would have been better than using a pointer to an argument-less function, but the Standard seems to more focused on removing concepts from the language than offering a viable alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to have separate compilation, meaning that the call versus the definition of a function might be in separate source files, compiled at different times, perhaps months or years apart, you need to decide how information passed to and returned from the function is going to be coordinated.

Let's cover the return value first.  Functions can be declared to return `int`, or `double`, or `char *`, or just about any of C's other types.  (There are one or two exceptions, types which it's impossible to return, but they needn't concern us here.)  But for any given ABI, different values get returned in different ways.  Integers and pointers might get returned in a general-purpose processor register.  Floating-point values might get returned in a floating-point register.  Structures might get returned in some specially-designated memory area.  In any case, the called function is going to do the returning, but the calling function (compiled separately) is going to do something with the returned value, so it has to know how to emit the right code to do that.  And the only way for it to know (again, under C's separate-compilation model) is the function declaration that indicated the return type.  If the calling code thought the function was going to return an `int`, but the called function actually returned a double, it just wouldn't work, because the called function would place its return value in the spot where return values of type `double` go, and the calling code would fetch a value from the place where return values of type `int` go, and it would get indeterminate garbage instead.

Now let's talk about the arguments passed *to* the function.  Again, the mechanisms behind argument passing can take several forms, depending on the type(s) of the argument(s).  Again, mismatches are easy, but can cause serious problems.  *If* the programmers writing calling code could be relied on to always pass the correct number of arguments, and of the correct types, we wouldn't need function prototypes — and indeed, that's how C was for the first few years of its life.  These days, however, that risk is generally considered as unacceptable, and function prototypes are considered mandatory — by the language standard, by compilers, and by most C programmers.  (You might still find a few holdouts, grumbling that prototypes are newfangled or unnecessary, but they're basically an ignorable minority.)

There's a remaining wrinkle concerning "varargs" functions such as `printf`.  Since they don't accept a fixed number of fixed-type arguments, they can't have a prototype that specifies the types of those arguments in advance.  An ellipsis ("`...`") in a function prototype indicates variable arguments that (a) can't be enforced by the compiler but that (b) do have the *default argument promotions* performed on them, to provide a little more regularity (basically, small types like `char` and `int` promoted to `int`, and `float` promoted to `double`).  Varargs functions, too, are generally consider old-school and risky if not downright dangerous, and are not recommended for new designs, unless perhaps if they follow the pattern of `printf`, meaning that the compiler *can* peek at the format string (if constant) and do the programmer the favor of double-checking the arguments.

The requirements here have been evolving ever since C was invented, and (as discussed in the comments) are still changing.  If you have specific questions about what's legal and what's not, what works and what won't, you might want to ask them explicitly, but the answer may depend on which version of C we're talking about.

We can get a good picture of most of the issues just by looking at the standard `sqrt` function.  Suppose you say

```
double x = sqrt(144);
```

Once upon a time, that was doubly wrong.  Once upon a time, without a function declaration in scope, `sqrt` would be assumed to return `int`, meaning that this call wouldn't work, because `sqrt` *actually* returns a `double`.  (The compiler would emit code to fetch an `int` and convert it to the `double` required by `x`, but this would be meaningless since there's no `int` actually returned by `sqrt` to convert.)  But, there's a second problem: `sqrt` accepts a `double` argument, which this code doesn't pass, so `sqrt` wouldn't even receive the correct value to take the square root of.

So, once upon a time, you absolutely needed

```
extern double sqrt();
```

(which you probably got from `<math.h>`) to tell the compiler that `sqrt` returned a `double`, and it was your responsibility to call

```
double x = sqrt(144.);
```

or

```
double x = sqrt((double)144);
```

to cause a `double` value to be passed.

Today, if you call `sqrt` out of a clear sky (that is, without a declaration in scope), the compiler is more likely to complain that there's no prototype in scope — that is, it will not quietly assume that `sqrt` returns `int`.  And if there *is* a declaration in scope, it will be the prototype declaration

```
extern double sqrt(double);
```

which explicitly says that `sqrt` expects one argument of type `double`.  So, today, the code

```
double x = sqrt(144);
```

works fine — the compiler knows to implicitly convert the `int` value `144` to `double` before passing it to `sqrt`.

If you did something *really* wrong, like calling `sqrt(44, 55)`, in the old days you'd get no complaints (and a very wrong answer), while today you'll get an error saying you've passed too many arguments.

This is probably a longer answer than you were looking for, but in closing, there are two final points to make:

1. No one would claim that any of this makes perfect sense, or is the way you'd design things from scratch, today.  We're living (as ever) with a number of imperfect compromises between modernity and backwards compatibility.
2. The "guarantees" apparently promised by function prototypes — namely, that automatic argument conversions will be performed if possible, and that compile-time errors will be emitted for gross mismatches — are not absolute, and still depend on a certain amount of programmer care, namely to ensure that the prototypes (upon which everything depends) are *actually correct*.  This generally means putting them in `.h` files, included both by the caller and the defining source file.  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401100) exploring how those vital conventions might be enforced.

Comment: At the risk of commenting on an (as yet) incomplete answer, I think you've got some hidden assumptions going on here.  Compare Python, for example.  It does not require parameter types or return types to be declared, and CPython performs separate compilation.  It all works together fine.  I understand well why that is and how C is different, but I would guess that the OP does not.

Comment: Also, there is as of yet (or is there in the latest standard? maybe) no requirement to declare parameters, and as long as definition and actual call agree, that is just fine: The call is the ad-hoc declaration, if you want. That would also work for the return type (akin to `auto`declarations in C++) but C *chose* to imply int instead. So yes: The compiler must know what parameter- and return-types are -- but it could simply infer that. The reason an explicit declaration is required is not technical; it's just safety through redundancy.

Comment: How would one write C23 code that could call an outside function `void test(void(*)(void (*)(), int), int);`?

Comment: @Peter Well, it's a *bit* more complicated than that, due to default argument promotions.  Also, AIUI, C23 will redefine `extern int f();` to be `extern int f(void);`.

Comment: @Peter I don't see a way around explicit declaration of the return type — implicit `int` is long gone, and C will never (IMO) have anything like `auto`.  If you were going to infer a function's return type from context, it would seem to me you would also have to make `double f = 1 / 2;` work "properly", and that's a breaking change I don't see ever happening.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't know how CPython does it, either!  I was definitely weaseling when I referred (several times) to "C's separate-compilation model", ducking the question of how other type-safe separate-compilation models might work.

Comment: @SteveSummit, loosely speaking, Python does it by relying on the fact that every Python value carries information about its type, and this is used at runtime to evaluate expressions.  Nothing like that applies to C.

Comment: @SteveSummit, it turns out that C23 *does* have type inference with `auto` (section 6.7.9 of that spec).  It is only specified for object declarations that include an initializer, but the committee appears to to have taken care to leave other type-inference cases unspecified (J.6.3), as opposed to making their behavior undefined or a constraint violation. The only constraint in this area is that "A declaration for which the type is inferred shall contain the storage-class specifier `auto`."

Answer (score 0):

***Because C Compilers compile code row from top to bottom.*** If you gonna use any function in your main function you have two ways to do that.

1. You can code your function first then use main(Compiler code row from top to bottom so it will figure out there is a function)
2. Like you do you can use parameters to say **"Hey there is a function that i made i will use that later"** to Compiler.

Comment: C compilers *do* compile in one pass from top to bottom, or at least the language is specified in such a way that doing so is possible.  But that doesn't explain why parameter types need to be declared.  This answer seems to miss the point.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

- Declaration without parameters. COMPILES.
- Declaration without parameters and either without type. COMPILES BUT WARNING.
- Call BEFORE definition (and no declaration). Compile error. ERROR.

Compiles perfectly (as @Vlad from Moscow pointed, neither parameters are needed in declaration):

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 
  3 int sum ();     // no parameters declaration (if also omit type int, will compile but with warning
  4 
  5 int main (void)
  6 {
  7         int numa = 2, numb = 3;
  8 
  9         printf ("Sum %d + %d = %d\n", numa, numb, sum ( numa, numb ));
 10 
 11         return 0;
 12 }
 13 
 14 int sum ( int numa, int numb )
 15 {
 16         return numa + numb;
 17 }
```

output:

```
./ftype_def_dec                    
Sum 2 + 3 = 5
```

type int of function ommited (compiled but with warning):

```
gcc -o ftype_def_dec ftype_def_dec.c
ftype_def_dec.c:3:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
sum ();
^
1 warning generated.
```

Does not compile (if you omit declaration in a function called in main() BEFORE it's DEFINITION [every detail [types & what/how it does explicited]]):

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 
  3 // int sum ();
  4 
  5 int main (void)
  6 {
  7         int numa = 2, numb = 3;
  8 
  9         printf ("Sum %d + %d = %d\n", numa, numb, sum ( numa, numb ));
 10 
 11         return 0;
 12 }
 13 
 14 int sum ( int numa, int numb )
 15 {
 16         return numa + numb;
 17 }

gcc -o ftype_def_dec ftype_def_dec.c
ftype_def_dec.c:9:44: error: implicit declaration of function 'sum' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        printf ("Sum %d + %d = %d\n", numa, numb, sum ( numa, numb ));
                                                  ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: The question does not ask what is allowed.  It asks *why*.

Comment: @John Bollinger Yes, there was a "why" in the title. But finally it was a lot of things. Implicit (or even explicit, depending on perspective), it was a "what", it was "everything", because it was mixing order of things, with allegedly language design principles, even asking for some historical development? Who knows... ? For some reason it ended the way it did. 
Thank you for your comment, nice to extend reflections on the post.

Answer (score 0):

**Because the compiler has to be able to know how your function can be called and used** (i.e. what parameters it accepts and what its return type is (although the former can be omitted)) **in other calling functions (such as in `main`).**

As mentioned by another answer, the compiler will compile your program from top to bottom. Thus, when it reaches a given line in your program where you use your function, if you had not previously declared it, it would not know how to parse and compile that statement, and/or be able to detect if it consists of an error.

Take a simple example:

```c
void square(int*);

int main(void) {
    
    int number = 4;
    
    number = square(number); // ERROR
    // correct usage would be:
    square(&number);
    return 0;
}

void square(int *num) {
    if (!num)
        return;
    *num *= *num;
}
```

However, if you had not declared `square` before `main`, the compiler would have no way of knowing what do with your call to `square` inside `main`, or which of the two calls was an error.

In other words, `square` is an *undeclared identifier* if you have not declared the function before calling it.

Just like you cannot do something like:

```c
int main(void) {
    int x = 2;
    y = x + 5; // ERROR: undeclared identifier 'y'
    int y;
    return 0;
}
```

... because the compiler has no idea what `y` is by the time it reaches its first usage.

Comment: And yet, K&R C did not require functions to be declared before use, and didn't even have a mechanism to forward-declare function parameters.  C90 did not require function return types or parameter numbers or types to be declared prior to calls to the function (with some caveats).  Even C17 does not require function parameter numbers or types to be declared prior to function calls (again, with some caveats).

Comment: None of the declarations are, technically, necessary (in particular, an old C compiler would infer that `square` is a function taking an int parameter, and assume that it returns an int (which is discarded). This leniency can, of course, mask errors which is why successive C standards are demanding more and more explicitness. The progress there is slow; it basically trails the phasing out of legacy software made non-conforming by the changes.