# Is there some way to mark a function definition as out-of-line?

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I have a tool-chain in which header files are generated (by `javac -h`, i.e. Java Native Interface), but the implementation of the functions is manually written. It would be really useful to get an error message when a supposed implementation function doesn’t actually implement a header-declared function (usually because the header function was updated).

I know how I would do that if the header functions were in a namespace:

```cpp
#pragma once
namespace N
{
    void f();
}
```

```cpp
#include "header.hpp"
void N::f() { }
// good: compile error when you change the declaration in the header!
```

The function defined by `N::f()` won’t compile without the declaration (in the header).

However, the generator doesn’t put stuff in namespaces (and I found no way to tell it to), so I tried the global namespace, but that is apparently not allowed:

```cpp
#pragma once
void f();
```

```cpp
#include "header.hpp"
void (::f)() { }
// error (on MSVC)
// warning "extra/explicit qualification on member 'f'" (on Clang/GCC)
```

I have to support MSVC, so suppressing the warning is not an option.

As a last resort, because all the functions are `extern "C"`, I thought I could maybe wrap the `#include "header.hpp"` in a `namespace`, but that didn’t work either.

I’m out of ideas. Is this plain unsolvable?

Comment: I’m on my phone now so I cannot test it, but shouldn’t taking the address of a declared yet undefined function trigger a linker error?

Comment: I don’t think that works. First, ideally, I want compile errors not link errors. Secondly, when I only look at the cpp file and arbitrarily take the address of functions defined there, they’re of course defined, irrespective of whether they’re declared in the header.

Comment: AFAIK JNI is bridge into a C not C++, so namespaces are not available. Problem is C++ name mangling.

Comment: The JNI header tests for `__cplusplus`, so it’s clearly C++ as well as C; if it can insert `extern "C"` conditionally, it can – in principle – insert a namespace. I use C++; if the solution is C++-only, I don’t care.

Comment: `void ::f() {}` [is actually valid](https://wg21.link/CWG482) (and compiles on MSVC/clang), but a [gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64267) makes this not compile on gcc so it's not that helpful if you need to support gcc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution and it’s actually pretty, but rather hacky.

Simply putting the include of the generated header in a namespace doesn’t work:

```cpp
namespace jni
{
#include "header.hpp"
}
```

The problems do not stem from what’s in `header.hpp` directly, but from what’s in `jni.h` that the generated header includes.

But, because `jni.h` has header protections, one can include `jni.h` in the implementation file before including the generated header!

```cpp
#include <jni.h>
namespace jni
{
#include "header.hpp"
}

// Here, all the generated functions are in namespace jni.
```

Because all the generated functions are `extern "C"`, for the JNI to call them, it doesn’t matter if C++ put them in namespaces. Because C has no namespace, in the object file, the namespaces are gone!

Answer (score 3):

You can at least get a warning with GCC or Clang by using the appropriate flag:

- `-Wmissing-declarations` for GCC
- `-Wmissing-prototypes` for Clang

Clang also provides `-Wmissing-declarations` but it does not do the same thing.

GCC also provides `-Wmissing-prototypes` but not for C++, I'm not sure why.

[See also this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50401672/3854570)

Comment: That’s a good partial solution; partial because my team develops on MSVC and this isn’t a good enough reason to switch.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find an equivalent flag for MSVC.